# Does the $Z$ pentomino tile a 3D box?

Tags: 3d, tiling, polyomino

Some polyominoes are *rectifiable*, meaning they can tile some rectangle in the plane. For instance, the following tiling shows the $Y$-pentomino is rectifiable:

[image]

On the other hand, some polyominoes (like the $S$-tetromino) are not, as should be obvious from trying a few configurations.

However, the $S$-tetromino *does* tile a $2\times 3\times 4$ box, if we consider the corresponding polycube. (Shown below is a sliced-open view of the tiling, with projections onto two of the faces shown off to the side.)

[image]

In fact, of the eight non-rectifiable pentominoes, I've found tilings for six of them:

- The $R$ pentomino tiles a $5\times 6\times 6$ box.
- The $S$ pentomino tiles a $2\times 4\times 5$ box.
- The $T$ pentomino tiles a $3\times 10 \times 10$ box.
- The $U$ pentomino tiles a $2\times3\times5$ box.
- The $V$ pentomino tiles a $3\times5\times6$ box.
- The $W$ pentomino tiles a $5\times6\times6$ box.

The $X$ pentomino obviously cannot tile any box, because it can never fit in the corner.

This leaves the $Z$ pentomino:

[image]

It's not apparent that it would find obstacles when trying to fit, but my computer-based search hasn't found any tilings of the shape within boxes of volume less than $360$. (Though given the minimum-volume boxes listed above, it's not clear this is all that strong evidence of impossibility.)

Questions about this problem:

- Is there a known tiling or a known disproof?
- Is there a coloring argument that restricts the possible dimensions beyond the trivial considerations (at least one side a multiple of $5$ and all dimensions at least $3$)?
- Is there literature more generally on the problem of tiling boxes with polycubes, or pieces of the literature on rectifiable polyominoes that carry over?
- If the $Z$ pentomino can't tile a three-dimensional box, can it tile one of a higher dimension?

Comment: You should add the definition of the Z pentomino to have this question be more self-contained.

Comment: This is an excellent question!

Comment: As an aside: I read in one of Gardner's books that one copy of all 12 pentominoes (with a thickness of one unit) will tile 3×4×5, 2×5×6 and 2×3×10 boxes.

Comment: On [Torsten Sillke's site](https://www.math.uni-bielefeld.de/~sillke/results.html) you can find results for all the pentacubes, including [the Z-pentacube](https://www.math.uni-bielefeld.de/~sillke/PENTA/qu5-z) for which 6x6x25 and 6x10x10 solutions are known.

Comment: @JaapScherphuis: Thanks! Happy to accept this as an answer if you want to post it as such.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

On [Torsten Sillke's site](https://www.math.uni-bielefeld.de/%7Esillke/results.html) you can find results for all the pentacubes, including [the Z-pentacube](https://www.math.uni-bielefeld.de/%7Esillke/PENTA/qu5-z) for which 6x6x25 and 6x10x10 solutions are known. They were found by Yoshiya Wolf Shindo in 1997.

The 6x10x10 solution has 4-fold rotational symmetry around one axis, and 2-fold around the other axes, so it consists of 8 copies of a single shape of approximately size 3x5x5 that fit together to form the block.

```
   51 52 52 36 38 30 30 21 15 15
   51 52 40 36 36 36 30 21 21 21
   52 52 53  z 33 36 30 30 14 21
   53 53 53  z  z  z  z  z 23 23
   53 55 55  z  z  z  z 22 23 11
   54 55 41  z  z  z  z 23 23 24
   55 55  z  z  z  z  z 24 24 24
   56 44 42 42 34 35  z 24 25 25
   56 56 56 42 34 34 34 29 25 12
   57 57 56 42 42 31 34 25 25 12

   47 47 38 38 38 27 26 26 15 19
   51 47 40 40 40 28 28 19 19 19
   48 47 47  z 33 33 33 19 14 11
   48 43 41  z  z  z  z  z 14 11
   49 43 41  z  z  z  z 22 14 11
   54 44 41  z  z  z  z 22 13 17
   54 44  z  z  z  z  z 22 13 10
   54 44 50 35 35 35  z 20 20 10
   50 50 50 37 37 29 29 29 20 12
   50 57 39 39 32 31 31 31 20 20

   45 45 38  o  o 27 26 15 15 16
   51 45  o  o 40 27 28 16 16 16
   51 45 45  z  o 27 33 16  o 11
   48 43 41  z  z  z  z  z  o  o
   49 49 49  z  z  z  z  o 14  o
    o 44  o  z  z  z  z 17 17 17
    o  o  z  z  z  z  z 22 13 10
   54  o 46 35 32  o  z 18 18 12
   46 46 46 37 32 29  o  o 18 12
   46 57 57 39 32  o  o 31 18 18

    .  .  .  .  . 26 26  .  .  .
    .  .  .  .  .  . 28 28  .  .
    . 43  .  .  . 27  .  .  .  .
   48 43  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .
   48  . 49  .  .  .  .  .  .  .
    .  .  .  .  .  .  . 17  . 10
    .  .  .  .  .  .  .  . 13 10
    .  .  .  . 32  .  .  . 13  .
    .  . 37 37  .  .  .  .  .  .
    .  .  . 39 39  .  .  .  .  .
```